# Couldn't build PySide2 in mingW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, pyside

This is second day I'm working on building [PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2_GettingStarted)

I couldn't build PySide2 via mingW on windows.( with regard to developer orders)

Sources and system:

- Windows 10 x64
- Qt 5.6.1 prebuilt : (qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.1-1.exe)
- mingw 4.9.2 (included in Qt : Qt5.6.1\Tools\mingw492_32)
- perl (ActivePerl-5.24.0.2400)
- cmake (cmake-3.6.1-win32-x86)
- openssl and other needed libs.
- Pyside2 last repo (http://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/)

(These were recommended versions for building PySide2)
Below lines are the last out put of compiler.

```
[ 64%] Building CXX object tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/templateptr.cpp.obj
[ 64%] Building CXX object tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/transform.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\Qt\PySide2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp:28:0:
C:\Qt\PySide2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp:30:20: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
 static inline bool isfinite(double a) { return _finite(a); }
                    ^
C:\Qt\PySide2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp:30:20: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
C:\Qt\PySide2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp:30:20: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
C:\Qt\PySide2\pyside-setup\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp:30:20: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
tests\libsample\CMakeFiles\libsample.dir\build.make:1137: recipe for target 'tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/transform.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/transform.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3040: recipe for target 'tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [tests/libsample/CMakeFiles/libsample.dir/all] Error 2
makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Error compiling shiboken2
```

As you see it compiles upto 64% of source code but errors on `\sources\shiboken2\tests\libsample\transform.cpp`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Currently PySide2 does not support mingw. There are no plans on the [roadmap](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2) for this either.

Comment: @IronManMark20 Really??So I waste my time on,; thanks man

Comment: sadly yes, however, if you want, you could always [submit a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE/fixforversion/15785/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel) and see if they will commit to supporting it, but they may just say they won't.

Comment: @IronManMark20 , you right, but i just need it right now.I redownload 2013 version of Qt built package and I'm trying to build PySide2 with VC++2012. if it didn't work then I should download VS 2013 express(about 6.4 GB) and redo the Job. more sophisticated process. I wish there were PySide2 binaries that I could download and focus on coding,

Comment: actually there are some [unofficial binaries](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels)

Comment: thanks, also it need MSVS 2015 that should I download , 2012 version didn't not work. BTW I mean PySide binaries not Qt(that i have already)